# Does HTML minification code contains closing of body tag?

Tags: html, minify

I have implemented HTML minification in my MVC application. My main question is Does HTML minification code contains closing of body tag? And if not can I add it? How?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Tierarzneimittel, Di&#228;tfutter und Futtermittel von Tierarzt24</title>
      <meta charset=UTF-8>
      <meta name=description content="Tierarzt24 ist ein Tierarztshop &amp; Tierapotheke. Bei uns finden Sie günstige Tierarzneimittel und Futtermittel für Hunde, Katzen &amp; Pferde.">
      <meta name=keywords content="Royal Canin Urinary,Tierarzt,Tierapotheke,Royal Canin Renal,Tierbedarf,Katzenfutter,Urinary,Tiernahrung,Tierfutter,Hundefutter,Haustiere,Tierzubehör,Hunde,Katze,Heimtierbedarf,Futterergänzungsmittel,Futtermittel,Pferdefutter">
      <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name=generator content=nopCommerce>
      <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
      <link href="/bundles/styles/iwanw-dwjibdjlcog05flw8hzbcilynxp1opaz3l_ha1?v=bXWPjtSqIY20iUma132StQ5mLP1pi9ZZJjwVWEqN3OA1" rel=stylesheet>
      <script src="/bundles/scripts/jet7uikpmxtqk6rqznrtdlh6-hkgi1ng7ngnrghjhja1?v=0y6Z9gZZZi_E4o-8Shc-7ADTGI6tr12-7NGHPpOMpO41"></script>
      <link rel=canonical href=test-equi.com>
      <link href=http://test-equi.com/blog/rss/3 rel=alternate type=application/rss+xml title="Tierarzt24.de: Blog">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href=http://test-equi.com/favicon.ico>
      <script async id=mini-profiler src="/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=uZxmJ8Mst1yfwoTlTBen3ZVQs12agJzT0AK6jmyml/s=" data-version="uZxmJ8Mst1yfwoTlTBen3ZVQs12agJzT0AK6jmyml/s=" data-path="/mini-profiler-resources/" data-current-id=45b34f0b-f4cb-4b0b-8352-faddfec22d4b data-ids=2f0a3782-43db-423b-996d-fa1f2cede46a,e904360f-bbb6-4d4b-8ecd-9c91f8b2f6f2,3f486935-bc33-437a-af69-cc99b86afd62,b59194d9-9e97-4498-af7e-00bf38018f4b,41e54775-3585-4558-a11f-d750cd574321,7e05d9ce-ad18-46b8-80d6-06c6f1d3873a,a8e4e578-c039-4771-8cd7-2eeed11ff0b1,cd78e450-d121-486f-9896-f111fe66f834,501cb098-fce0-48c2-9da6-54fde88ac3a7,967236dd-5229-4524-8f68-d7334abe196b,ad1b54d8-9309-43bb-8d9a-b387e6c146cb,9a24364c-8b5c-4521-a53e-b04efb483b95,e6e86852-87b9-4946-bab0-59455a4c25f8,1f344a6e-d1cc-4e82-bb81-943d122f6ab9,b1980200-e204-4bd6-afec-621fd2591631,45b34f0b-f4cb-4b0b-8352-faddfec22d4b data-position=left data-trivial=false data-children=false data-max-traces=15 data-controls=false data-authorized=true data-toggle-shortcut=Alt+P data-start-hidden=false data-trivial-milliseconds=2></script> <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src=https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js></script><![endif]-->
   <body>
      <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class=chromeframe>You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
      <![endif]--<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("#vet-searchterms[type=text]").focus(function(){if(this.value=='Ihre Adresse'){this.value='';}});$("#vet-searchterms[type=text]").blur(function(){if(this.value==''){this.value='Ihre Adresse';}});});function check_vet_search_form(){var search_terms=$("#vet-searchterms");if(search_terms.val()==""||search_terms.val()=="Ihre Adresse"){alert('Suchbegriffe eingeben');search_terms.focus();return false;}
                                 return true;}
                              </script>
                           </div> <script>$(document).ready(function(){$("li#topcartlink").mouseenter(function(){$('div#flyout-cart').addClass('active');});$("div.header").mouseenter(function(){$('div#flyout-cart').removeClass('active');});$("nav.top-menu").mouseleave(function(){$('div#flyout-cart').removeClass('active');});});</script></ul><div class=picture><a href=/royal-canin-urinary-so-katze-katzenfutter-lp-34 title="Zeige Details für Royal Canin Urinary S/O Katze Katzenfutter LP 34"> <img alt="Bild von Royal Canin Urinary S/O Katze Katzenfutter LP 34" src=http://test-equi.com/content/images/thumbs/0020833_royal-canin-urinary-so-katze-katzenfutter-lp-34_155.jpg title="Zeige Details für Royal Canin Urinary S/O Katze Katzenfutter LP 34"> </a></div>                                         </div> <script>var gts=gts||[];gts.push(["id","503918"]);gts.push(["badge_position","BOTTOM_RIGHT"]);gts.push(["locale","de_DE"]);gts.push(["google_base_subaccount_id","384762"]);gts.push(["google_base_country","{COUNTRY}"]);gts.push(["google_base_language","{COUNTRY}"]);(function(){var gts=document.createElement("script");gts.type="text/javascript";gts.async=true;gts.src="https://www.googlecommerce.com/trustedstores/api/js";var s=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(gts,s);})();</script><script>var callback=function(){var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;var width=((w.innerWidth=='undefined'||w.innerWidth==undefined)?$(window).width():window.innerWidth);var is_safari=((navigator.vendor=='undefined'||navigator.vendor==undefined)?(false):(navigator.vendor.indexOf("Apple")==0))&&(/\sSafari\//.test(navigator.userAgent));if(is_safari)
         {if((width<=767)||(width>=767&&width<=784))
         {$('div#main-header-menu').removeAttr('id');$("li#category-menu").removeClass('dropdown');$("ul#category-content").removeClass('dropdown-menu');}
         else if(width>=768&&width<=992){$('div.header-menu').attr('id','main-header-menu');$("li#category-menu").addClass('dropdown');$("ul#category-content").addClass('dropdown-menu');$("div#menu").addClass('container');}
         else{$('div.header-menu').attr('id','main-header-menu');$("div#menu").removeClass('container');}}
         else
         {if(width<=767)
         {$('div#main-header-menu').removeAttr('id');$("li#category-menu").removeClass('dropdown');$("ul#category-content").removeClass('dropdown-menu');}
         else if(width>=768&&width<=992){$('div.header-menu').attr('id','main-header-menu');$("li#category-menu").addClass('dropdown');$("ul#category-content").addClass('dropdown-menu');$("div#menu").addClass('container');}
         else{$('div.header-menu').attr('id','main-header-menu');$("div#menu").removeClass('container');}}
         if($('html').hasClass('eq-ie8')){$('.custom-checkbox').removeClass('custom-checkbox');$('.custom-radio').removeClass('custom-radio');}};$(window).load(callback);$(window).resize(callback);
      </script><script id=sourcecode>$(window).load(function(){$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();});</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: minification is just removing white space and unneccessary lines to reduce the size of the file. So you still need complete HTML structure such as closing tag.

Comment: Minification removes closing of HTML and BODY. Is there any way to add it to all my view pages.

Comment: Minification have all the html tag so i think your script for minifying the html code is wrong. but your html code still work good because browser auto render that closing tags.

Comment: Which minifier? Provide a sample of input and output.

Comment: @ torazaburo: I have implemented it using WebMarkupMin NuGet package

Comment: Can you show us the input and output? I'd be very surprised if any minifier removed closing HTML or BODY tags.

Comment: @torazaburo: I have updated my code.

Comment: Your HTML seems to be invalid because it contains script tags which contain special HTML characters such as`<`. Try minifying with no JS and see if that solves the problem. If you can't externalize your JS, which you probably should anyway, then I suppose you could wrap the script in a CDATA section.